# Order functions in .cpp files to match order in .h files in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, formatting

I've written a lot of functions without paying attention to their order and it has gotten kind of messy.

I want to make my code more readable by having the order of functions in my .cpp files match the order in the .h files. Is there a way to do this automatically in Visual Studio 2015 or do I have to do it manually?

What other options are there to automatically format my code to make it more readable in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Do you know how to do the opposite?    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582286

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort method implementations according to their declaration order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260500/how-can-i-sort-method-implementations-according-to-their-declaration-order)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in feature to do this. However you can collapse all of your implementations using Ctrl+M then Ctrl+O to make it easier to manipulate them. Ctrl+M then Ctrl+P disabled outlining after your done.

For the second part of your question, press Ctrl+K then Ctrl+F to automatically format any highlighted code. Ctrl+K then Ctrl+D automatically formats the entire document. The formatting rules are controlled in Tools->Options...->Text Editor->C/C++.

Other useful shortcuts can be found in Edit->Advanced or Edit->Outlining.